# Bulk email rate-limiting methods for CiviMail in WordPress shared hosting environment?

Tags: wordpress, civimail

We just sent out our first bulk email through Civi 4.7.15 and WordPress 4.7.2 ... went off without a hitch, but in a matter of hours I received a nastygram from our hosting provider. Seems the terms of service prohibit sending more than 250 messages at once -- who knew?

To comply with the provider's TOS, we need to implement rate limiting. In other words, whenever we send a bulk email, the system needs to trickle the messages out at, say, 15 every 5 minutes (not all at once).

What rate limiting methods are available within CiviCRM to minimize the negative impacts on shared hosting servers when sending bulk email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to "Administer>CiviMail>Mailer Settings" there are several options. You are probably looking to use Mail Batch Limit which limits the number of emails sent each time the mail job runs.

Comment: Thanks -- I was just going to post that information. Strange that it couldn't be found in the Civi documentation when searching for it.